# Can not start Android emulator

Tags: android-emulator

Android emulator starts and dies after seconds. In error log I get following error message:
`Emulator: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)`

I found following solution

```
$ cd Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++
$ mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
$ ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
```

but in my lib64 folder I do not have the file `libstdc++.so.6` which i could change to `.bak`

Comment: After restart my machine it works, but sadly I do not know why.